# How can I use ieeeconf.cls file in root.tex in TexStudio?

Tags: document-classes

I've been trying to use the `ieeeconf.cls` file with the `root.tex` file, but I just can't get that work.

I import like this: `\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}` but I get the following error, when I hover the mouse on that line:

> Class: ieeeconf
>
> (not found)

And when I try to compile the `root.tex` file I get the following logs (the one about `/maketitle` I think it's becasue the `ieeeconf` is not loading properly):

[image]

But the files are in the same folder, like this:

[image]

The links of the files are [from ieee site](http://embs.papercept.net/conferences/support/tex.php#latexclass) and I'm using the following to build:

[image]

Comment: The error about the class could just mean that TexStudio (the editor) does not know where the class file is, that is not really a problem as long as latex/pdflatex (the compiler) can find it - and this seems to be the case, otherwise you would get an error about the missing file at the start of your log instead of an inputenc error.

Comment: The inputenc error itself indicates that something is wrong with the character encoding of the file or the special (accented etc.) characters used inside the file. Make sure you save the file as utf8. To find out exactly what the problem is you can post your file here as part of the question, with the content removed as much as possible while the error remains, then the community here can take a look at it (you can press the small `edit` button below the question to add code).

Comment: @Troy I tried and the result is the same.

Comment: @Marijn Nice, that's correct about the class file, I renamed to other file and get the error, then the import is working.

Comment: @Marijn thank you, your tip make me find the errors, I posted a answer with my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the file I took from IEEE were coded in ANSI format, I also noticed that some characters were strange, and when I removed some of them the paragraphs with error disappeared.

Then, I needed to do were just remove the unknown characters from the `.tex` file (in my case, I used the VSCode, just opened the file and the characters with `<?>` I made a *replace all*.